# toggleClass doesn't seem to apply here. Any clue why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

Using waypoint library, however, the problem seems NOT to be related with the script, either, with our bad understanding over general jquery and javascript comprehension.

With this line, we are hopping to select ALL anchors where attribute href as a certain value, and add or remove a class.

```
$('a[href="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').toggleClass("marca-menu", direction === 'down');
```

But nothing happens.

The code, and below, the fiddle.

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {   
   $('#container section').each(function() {            
     $(this).waypoint(function(direction) {
       $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').toggleClass("marca-menu", direction === 'down');
     });
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="main-menu">
<ul>
 <li><a href="#slide3" target="_self">plimplim</a></li>
 <li><a href="#slide4" target="_self">plimplomm</a></li>
 <li><a href="#slide5" target="_self">plimplumm</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<section id="slide3">
  <h1>bababaadasda</h1>
    <p>asdsadasdsad</p>
    <p>asdsadasdsad</p>
    <p>asdsadasdsad</p>
    <p>asdsadasdsad</p>
    <p>asdsadasdsad</p>
</section>
<section id="slide4">
 <h1>SLIDE 4</h1>
    <p>asdsadasdsad</p>
    <p>asdsadasdsad</p>
    <p>asdsadasdsad</p>
    <p>asdsadasdsad</p>
    <p>asdsadasdsad</p>
</section>
<section id="slide5">
 <h1>SLIDE 5</h1>
    <p>asdsadasdsad</p>
    <p>asdsadasdsad</p>
    <p>asdsadasdsad</p>
    <p>asdsadasdsad</p>
    <p>asdsadasdsad</p>
</section>
```

CSS:
    nav {
        display:block;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        background: red;
    }

```
.marca-menu {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

You can check it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/talofo/Bkws7/

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Just updated the fiddle. Sorry.

Comment: You are not including waypoint plugin in your jsfiddle, not how you should

Comment: Thanks. Updated Fiddle Again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't saw your posted html, use that:

```
$('a[href="#' + this.id + '"]').toggleClass("marca-menu", direction === 'down');
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you for spotting that out. I notice you also used `this`, instead of `$(this)`... is there a difference ? (I can follow a link if more convenient then explained).

Comment: For attribute ID as it is a node element property, you don't need to use jquery, it is prefered here to use element property id instead. Just be aware that could not be applied to all attributes, e.g this.href will return absolute path while $(this).attr('href') will return relative path, the same for src